# Does the DockingManager come with a built-in method for handling Anchorables

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock, xceed

When setting up AvalonDock with a set of Anchorables, for example:

```
<a:LayoutRoot>
    <a:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">    
        <a:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            <a:LayoutAnchorable Title="A1">
                <!-- content -->
            </a:LayoutAnchorable>
            <a:LayoutAnchorable Title="A2">
                <!-- content -->
            </a:LayoutAnchorable>
    </a:LayoutAnchorablePane>
<!-- ... -->
```

Does the DockingManager (or something else in AvalonDock) come with a built-in way
of managing Anchorables that are closed? Are they stored in a collection somewhere so they can be retrieved and shown again?

For example, the user closes the first one from the code above (A1), what happens to it?
How can I display it again?

What's the typical workflow to deal with closing and restoring anchorables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you added the `xceed` tag, I assume you're using Avalondock 2.0.

> For example, the user closes the first one from the code above (A1),
>   what happens to it?

You anchorable becomes hidden. If you choose to name your anchorable (example: `<a:LayoutAnchorable Title="A1" x:Name="myAnchorable">`), you'll see in the code of your view that `this.myAnchorable.IsHidden` becomes `true`.

> How can I display it again?

Call `.Show()` against your anchorable: `this.myAnchorable.Show();`

---

That being said, Avalondock 2.0 is totally different from 1.0 because it now allows to use MVVM (especially bindings) easily. So the best practice would be to not statically add `LayoutAnchorable` in the XAML, but manage a collection of ViewModels instead (with a binding to the `AnchorablesSource` property of the `DockingManager`). Then it's easy to show/hide anchorables because you just have to get/set your ViewModel property that is bound to the `Visibility` property of `LayoutAnchorableItem`.

You could look at the WPF example Avalondock provides. It's the project named `AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp` in [their code source](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

Comment: Thank you, this really clears things up for me. Couldn't find it in the docs, and I hadn't looked at the source you mentioned (was looking at the extended toolkit page). The sample really helps. (I'll award in 6 hours, as I can't yet)

Comment: Following the binding examples works for most part, although the LayoutContent class of AvalonDock throws NullReference exceptions every time I try to hide a panel (actually, it tries to close it instead of hiding..) and once I hide a panel (setting visible to false, I can never make it visible again). Will probably post this in a separate question soon.

Comment: @TimothyP Did you ever figure out a solution for the null reference on hide? I am running into that issue as well.

Comment: @clcto not really. I did something really evil and just modified the avalondock source to ignore the error. Everything seemed to work fine then, but your mileage may vary. I've run into quite a few other issues with the toolkit as well...

Comment: @TimothyP I was using the default avalondock BooleanToVisibilityConverter, and that uses `Visibility.Collapsed` as the default when the value is `false`, not `Visibility.Hidden` which is what the anchorable expects when it is hidden. I will write a question and answer on Monday when I am in front of the source. In your binding you just have to add the parameter: `Visibility={Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}, Converter={StaticResource btvc}}`